# React Native - call a parent function from a utility class

Tags: react-native

I've setup react native push notifications with Firebase and local push notifications - both work fine.

On receiving a notification when the app is in the foreground (opened and focused) I am calling a local push notification which works fine as well.

Then, when the user clicks on the local notification, in the utility class there is an OnNotification method that is called and I need to set some state there which of course doesn't work.

So instead, I am trying to callback a function on the parent file (App.js) which does has access to state management. problem is the function in App.js is not accessible in the utility class (it's not a class component).

How can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance :)

Below is an simplified example of both files.

```
// App.js

import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Notifications from './src/utils/Notifications/Notifications'; // import the utility class.

const App = () => {

    // handles remote notification when app is in the FOREGROUND
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage = {}) => {
            // CALL FUNCTION ON UTILITY CLASS
            Notifications.localNotification(remoteMessage.data);
        });
        return unsubscribe;
    }, []);

    // THE CALLBACK FUNCTION PART
    const [someState, setSomeState] = useState('');
    const [someMoreState, setSomeMoreState] = useState('');

    const myFunc = (returnedData) => {
        setSomeState(returnedData.value_1)
        setSomeMoreState(returnedData.value_2)
    }


    return (
        <></>
    );
};

export default App;


// Notifications.js - utityly class.

    import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
    
    class Notifications {
  constructor() {
    PushNotification.configure({
      onNotification: function (notification) {
        if (notification.userInteraction) {
          // THIS IS TRIGGERED AFTER THE USER CLICKS THE NOTIFICATION - WORKS FINE.
          // HOW TO CALL FUNCTION HERE THAT NEEDS TO HANDLE STATE (function is in app.js)
            
            // example:
            const returnedData = {
                value_1: 'A',
                value_2: 'B',
            }

            myFunc(returnedData); // this function is in app.js 
        }
      },
    });
  }
    
      localNotification(data) {
      }
    
    }
    
    export default new Notifications();
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a function in App.js from components is not a good approach. As I understand it, you only need to access this function to set some state variables. A much better solution to your problem would be to use a shared state like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) or [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

You can then access this state from anywhere in your project and change it accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Context is not available inside the utitility class. There must be way to fire a callback function from the utility class

Comment: pass the function down as a prop until it reaches your utility class but that is a cumbersome approach. Try redux instead if you're having issue with Context

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question in case it might help somebody.
The only thing that worked for me is to refactor the Notifications class into App.js inside a useEffect()